# xml formatting in an email message

Tags: c#, html, xml, mailmessage

I am trying to send an email with C# code. the body of the email contains both of xml and html tags. email was sent and received successfuly. All HTML tags was being rendered and displayed correctly.

However the xml is loosing the formatting. Thats the code I used to pretty the xml

```
static string PrettyXml(string xml){
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var element = XElement.Parse(xml);
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.Indent = true;
//settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings))
{
    element.Save(xmlWriter);
}
return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

this is how i sent the email

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(fromField, toField, subject, emailBody);
mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

//
if (cc != string.Empty)
{
    MailAddress copy = new MailAddress(cc);
    mm.CC.Add(copy);
}

//
mm.IsBodyHtml = bodyHTML;
mm.Priority = MailPriority.High;

//
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1000;
client.EnableSsl = enableSsl;
client.Send(mm);
```

here how i escaped my xml

```
    private static string XMLEscape(string inputXML){
    string outXML = "";
    string ampersand = inputXML.Replace("&", "&amp;");
    string lessThan = ampersand.Replace("<", "&lt;");
    string greaterThan = lessThan.Replace(">", "&gt;");
    string quote = greaterThan.Replace(@"""", "&quot;");
    outXML = quote.Replace("'", "&apos;");
    return outXML;
    }
```

Your help is really appreciated

Comment: How are you escaping the xml tags inside the HTML?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include that. descrption was update with the escape xml code

Comment: I'd use [WebUtility.HtmlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlEncode_System_String_) instead of trying to roll your own

Comment: @RonBeyer I tried that but it doesnt work

Comment: What is the failure?  HtmlEncode will solve the tag issue.  There must be another issue.  May sure the xml string gets added to the body of the email.

Comment: @jdweng the body is getting attached correctly. I can see my text when I view the source of the email. Just noticed The indentation and line breaks aree not being encoded correctly

Comment: I ended up handling the line breaks and indentation manually. Simply by asking xmlwritersettings to put fake strings for these properties and then replace them by their html tags before sending the email. I find this as a work around. But  why did I need to do that?

Comment: XmlWriterSetting default to Ident = false.  Set to true.  Xml spec does not require returns.  The return will be different between linux and windows.

Comment: @jdweng This setting was set in prettyxml method

Comment: To get the xml string just use element.ToString().  I think the string builder is creating issues.

Comment: @jdweng just tried that with no luck. When I print the value of the encoded message I noticed that spaces and line breaks are not encoded properly.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  To see the hex values I use :  string results = string.Join(" ", element.ToString().Select(x => ((byte)x).ToString("X2")));

Comment: @jdweng right after I encoded the XML string, I did output the value of the encoded string. I am able to see space and not &nbsp; or <br> for line breaks

Comment: A <br> is html and not xml.  Since the xml is inside the html you will not see the html  tags.  I think the xml is the innertext of the html.

Comment: It is showing the right tags when I specify them explicitly in the settings .By inspecting xmlEscape(stringbuilder.tostring()), I can see it is encoding it to &lt;br;gt;